# Is there a function in R that will let me convert a dataset into "long format" but also merge columns?

Tags: r, function, wrangle

I have a dataset derived from Pokemon statistics containing a lot of the numerical and categorical data. My end goal is to create a model or recommendation system that a user can input a list of Pokemon and the model finds similar Pokemon they may like. Currently the dataset looks something like this:

```
ID   Name    Type1    Type2   HP  ATK   DEF
001  Bulba.. Grass    Poison  45  49    49
ect...
```

I want to convert this data into the "long format", because that format is friendlier with a lot of other functions in R, but I am having trouble dealing with the Type1/Type2 columns.
Is there a way I can merge those two into columns into a single column(like "Type") and then have the data converted into the new format? Something like this:

```
ID   Name    Type    Stat   Value
 001  Bulba.. Grass  HP     45
 001  Bulba.. Poison HP     45
 001  Bulba.. Grass  ATK    49
 001  Bulba.. Poison ATK    49
```

I understand for Pokemon of Dual-types it would make a pseudo entry, but I don't see any cleaner way to accomplish this. I also know about using dpylr's gather function but I can only really accomplish the Stat column using this method, not the Type issue.

Can anyone help me figure out how I can accomplish this or know any other more efficient methods?

Comment: What do you mean by "dual entry"? Is every row an "observation" per https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf? If so, go ahead and use ```tidyr::gather```.

Answer (score 1):

**1) pivot_longer** Reshape the data frame twice like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Type"), values_to = "Type") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_longer(c("HP", "ATK", "DEF"), names_to = "Stat", values_to = "Value")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  ID    Name    Type   Stat  Value
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <int>
1 001   Bulba.. Grass  HP       45
2 001   Bulba.. Grass  ATK      49
3 001   Bulba.. Grass  DEF      49
4 001   Bulba.. Poison HP       45
5 001   Bulba.. Poison ATK      49
6 001   Bulba.. Poison DEF      49
```

**2) melt**   Alternately use `melt` from data.table twice.

```
library(data.table)

m1 <- melt(DF, measure.var = grep("Type", names(DF)), value.name = "Type")
melt(m1, measure.var = c("HP", "ATK", "DEF"), 
  variable.name = "Stat", value.name = "Value")[-3]
```

giving:

```
   ID    Name   Type Stat Value
1 001 Bulba..  Grass   HP    45
2 001 Bulba.. Poison   HP    45
3 001 Bulba..  Grass  ATK    49
4 001 Bulba.. Poison  ATK    49
5 001 Bulba..  Grass  DEF    49
6 001 Bulba.. Poison  DEF    49
```

### Note

`DF` in reproducible form was assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "
ID   Name    Type1    Type2   HP  ATK   DEF
001  Bulba.. Grass    Poison  45  49    49"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, 
  colClasses = list(ID = "character"))
```

Comment: whenever I use pivot_longer() I get this "Error: Failed to create output due to bad names.
* Choose another strategy with `names_repair`
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace."

Comment: Copy and paste the code in the note into a fresh R session and then copy and paste the code in the answer.  You should get the output shown in the answer.

Comment: I still can't get it to work on my dataset. It looks like this:
`pokedex_number name       type1    type2  defense    hp attack sp_attack sp_defense speed base_total
 <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Bulbasaur  grass    poison      49    45     49        65         65    45        318`
And my code is this:
`DF %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("type"), values_to = "type") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
pivot_longer(c("defense","hp","attack","sp_attack","sp_defense","speed","base_total"), names_to = "Stat", values_to = "Value")`

Comment: In the question the column was called `Name` but in the example in your comment it was called `name` and that makes a big difference because `pivot_longer` without a `names_to=` argument by default produces a `name` column and there can't be two columns with the same column name.  Rename the input `name` column to be `Name` (or use the `names_to` argument in `pivot_longer` to specify a column name different from the `name` default and change the `select` statement accordingly).